# Google Vision Costum Server

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-vision

I use google vision to recognize pictures. Successful. But can I use it to train my own models on my own server?

```
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

labels = labels[:3]
```

instead of the remote request, you want to create your own infrastructure. To train my artificial intelligence, I want to use google vision. Does anyone want to do this as a resource or a paid job?

Answer (score 0):

You must be more specific but as far as I understand you should use AutoML Vision instead of Vision API if you want to create own models.

I recommend that you look at the tutorial here:

https://cloud.google.com/automl/?hl=tr